# Is there a way to render an IDWriteTextLayout starting from a different position than x=0 / y=0?

Tags: direct2d, directwrite

When you have a TextLayout which is just partially visible and don't want to render everything, are there any methods to change the startingpoint for rendering?

```
CComPtr<ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget>        _bitmaprendertarget;
_bitmaprendertarget->DrawTextLayout(D2D1_POINT_2F{ (FLOAT)x, (FLOAT)y }, tLayout, _solidColorBrush, D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_CLIP);
```

In this example x and y reflect just the destination point where the TextLayout is drawn to on the rendertarget.
I am looking for a way to render it partially instead - so it doesn't get drawn completely.

Comment: The most simple way is to clip the render target https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-pushaxisalignedclip(constd2d1_rect_f__d2d1_antialias_mode)

Comment: Yes, just set a clip, and use DrawTextLayout(origin) to position output.

Comment: So using a Layer is the only way?

Comment: PushAxisAlignedClip is not a layer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-layers-overview#alternatives-to-layers

Comment: @PWeiss, another option might be to set layout size with SetMaxWidth/SetMaxHeight, and then use D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_CLIP.